# How to avoid Drupal 7 user ID in user path?

Tags: drupal-7, hook-menu

I have the following in my theme:

```
$items['user/%user/sms-services'] = array(
    'title' => t('SMS Services'),
    'page callback' => 'sms_user_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

It works great in that it:

1. Creates a url /user/USER_ID/sms-services
2. Creates a tab on the /user page

However, I want to get rid of the USER ID part. I.e. The link must work as:

```
/user/sms-services
```

And /user/USER_ID/sms-services must redirect to /user/sms-services

And /user/USER_ID must redirect to /user

Is there an easy way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I used the "me aliases" module to accomplish much of this, but it's still not a very elegant solution, because now i'm stuck with TWO urls working:

```
/user/me/some-action
```

AND

```
/users/393/some-action
```

When all I really wanted was:

```
/user/some-action
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do sometinhg like this instead. Check if the user entering user/sms-services is logedin by using user_is_logged_in, if true use the global $user for further stuff. 
Maybe something like this

```
$items['user/sms-services'] = array(
    'title' => 'SMS Services',
    'page callback' => 'sms_user_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
); 

function sms_user_page(){
    if(user_is_logged_in){//Just realize, with 'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in' in the menu item array this if is unnecesary
      global $user;
      $user->uid;

      //Do stuff
    }
}
```

And maybe make a drupal_goto() from the old ones (menu items with the user wildcard to the new ones)

**Very importat:**

Do not use t() function in your menu item. By defualt drupal will pass the title string into the function t(). You can change that behavior by setting a new 'title callback' in your menu item array

See hook_menu from drupal.org

Comment: Indeed, the global user can be recover anywhere and you can avoid to pass it through the URL. I'll give a try to Gianni's solution if I were you.